# Sending different responses on angular component based on button pressed

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

Currently, I have a button that sends some information to update fields on the backend based on a function I have on my component that works as a parameter for a lot of other fields. Which means that if I change the value of a field from **x** to **2x**, the backend will also update those fields that depends on these values.

[image]

Code:

```
export class ParametersComponent implements OnInit {

  parametersForm: FormGroup;
  parameters: parameters;
  sequence: number;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private service: ParametersService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.parametersForm = this.fb.group({
      // id: ['', [Validators.required]],
      percMin: ['', [Validators.required]],
      percInicial: ['', [Validators.required]],
      percfrete: ['', [Validators.required]],
      percCustoOperac: ['', [Validators.required]],
      decimal: ['', [Validators.required]],
      icmClient: [''],
      useIcmClient: [''],
      type: ['']
    })
    this.route.parent?.params.subscribe(
      (params: any) => {
        this.sequence = params['id'];
        const parameters$ = this.service.loadParameters(this.sequence);
        parameters$.subscribe(
          dados => {
            this.parameters = dados;
            this.fillParametersForm();
          }
        )
      }
    )

  }


  fillParametersForm(){
    this.parametrosForm.patchValue({
      percMin: this.parameters.percMin,
      percInicial: this.parameters.percInicial,
      percfrete: this.parameters.percfrete,
      percCustoOperac: this.parameters.percCustoOperac,
      decimal: this.parameters.decimal,
      icmClient: this.parameters.icmClient,
      useIcmClient: this.parameters.useIcmClient
    });
  }

 parametersUpdate(){

    if(this.parametrosForm.valid){
      this.service.parametersUpdate(this.sequence, this.parametersForm.value).subscribe(
        dados => {
          console.log(dados)
          this.price();
        }
      )
    }
  }

  price(){
    const recalc$ = this.service.price(this.sequence);
    recalc$.subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    )
  }

}
```

## What I am trying to do:

- Create another button that does the exactly same thing, but only for one the fields. Lets say I want to update only the value of the first field which is the first one. I would change the value and click on that button, the backend would receive the request and would update only one field.

## My possible solution:

- I created a new field on my form (type) which would send a specific number when a specific button is pressed. So the logic is that on the backend, for example, **if type equals 1** **then update this field**, and so on.

I have been able to include this new field (type) in the request with a fixed value but I want to make it dinamic depending on the button pressed.

Is it possible to use this same function to send differente values by specifying which buttons (in the HTML) should do that?

Any other solution is also welcomed.